# Is there a Git command that allows you to copy files between local branches without accessing remote?

Tags: github

I do not want to push my changes up just yet so I am not going to checkout a file from master or any branch that is remote.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is such a command, called [merge](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge). You can merge a branch into another one, see more here: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging

Merging does not imply a push/pull from remote.